# Does a wireless receiver need always power?

Tags: switches, wireless, receiver

In a wireless switch system,

- does the receiver always have to have power or
- are there methods that allow to power the circuit only when it has received the signal?

Comment: As it stands, this is not specific enough to be answerable.  Passively powered radio receivers are possible, but to use with transmitters of legal power levels, generally only at very short ranges, ie, things like near field tags or with very special (and typically large) antennas.  At more normal "remote control" range you generally need a source of power for circuitry, but it is possible to to things like wake up the receiver to listen in  tiny time slices, if the transmitted signals lasts long enough to coincide with one of them.

Comment: Simple answer, no it does not need an external power supply, as you could use the energy of the signal to power a small speaker.

Comment: RFID tags are powered by the received signal and also transmit data back with this power.

Comment: What do you mean by " wireless switch"?  Example?

Comment: @transistor agreeing, but I don't think OP's question revolves around non-far field / inductive coupling / air core transformer data transmission as used in RFID; see my answer's paragraph on RFID.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I missed the word "switch" in the post but missing from the question title. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Please see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic There are guidelines that are recommended for writing good questions. This is a Q&A site, if there isn't a good question and it is broad the rest is speculation, questions need to be specific (not broad) and preferably have one answer.

Answer (score 1):

Contact less card and RFID tags use a magnetic field to power themself and transmit data.

The range for card is less than 5 cm and for RFID it can be few cm to 10m or more depending on the frequency used, antenna and other factors.

Comment: RFID is not really receiving a radio signal (OP didn't actually ask about radio propagation, but I *think* OP's intention was to ask about reception of far-field signals...); see my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be understood in two ways:

1. Is it possible to design a receiver that has no power source (battery, power supply...) of any kind? *or*
2. Is it possible to design a receiver that only consumes power when it's active, but is "ready for reception" continuously?

Re: **1. Is it possible to design a receiver that has no power source (battery, power supply...) of any kind?**

Of course! Radio waves have energy, and that energy can be used, not only amplified externally.

The classical example is the crystal radio: The current induced by the waves captured in an antenna is rectified, and used to drive a small earphone. Works splendidly, with all sorts of semiconductor rectifiers ("proper" diodes, rusty razor blades…)

RFID is kind of a borderline example of that, because, and I have to repeat that far too often, RFID is not what one typically calls radio: RFID is not based on waves propagating through space, but works basically by the fact that with coils in both the reader and the RFID tag, you can build an air-coil transformer. Still, these devices get powered only by what the reader transmits.

Also, there's a whole world of *energy harvesting* devices, even in ISM bands (where that behaviour is hard to implement legally), where energy is extracted from the signal, enough to actually drive an active receiver.

Re: **2. Is it possible to design a receiver that only consumes power when it's active, but is "ready for reception" continuously?**

Yes; well, depending on your understanding of "continuously".

In fact, this is how small receivers can last on a single coin cell for years – just turn on for a very short amount of time in a limited mode, sense whether there is some "known" wake-up signal on the air, and if it is, then fully power up and initiate full receiving capabilities.

That means that the transmitter needs to transmit that "wake-up call" for at least the period of time between two of these short sensing times, but that might be something in the dozens of milliseconds, still, so, for many purposes, that's kind of "continuous", with an extended preamble (many digital transceiver systems have preambles, anyway).

Taking this concept even further: Cellular phones would go through batteries extremely fast if they were fully listening all the time. Instead, they "know" at which moments there *might* be information coming in that concerns them, and typically, these times are short compared to the full operation span.

At these times, cellular base stations usually inform the handset that there will be more info coming in at specific times, so that the receiver can then be turned on again.

So, receivers that are turned off most of the time are very typical for modern systems that are based on some kind of Time-Division Multiple access (TDMA, multiple devices use the same part of the spectrum by making sure only one is sending/receiving at a time), or Time-Division Duplex (TDD, two devices send and receive on the same frequency, by making sure only one and is actively transmitting, whilst the other one is actively receiving).

Another energy preservation technique very common e.g. in satellite phones is to send a very strong signal to "ring up a phone", so that the phone's receiving amplifier can be driven in a very energy-efficient manner, and a more power-hungry RX mode is only entered when there's actually data to receive.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answare:):)I don't understand one thing:the receiver to stay in "hear mode" has to use energy,so in every two cases the receiver needs energy continously...or not?

Comment: Read my Re: **1.**